# Looking for a rigorous middle school self-study math course

Tags: algebra, self-learning, curriculum, middle-school

My son is in 5th grade (US) and since he is doing remote learning, we have been doing a lot of topics in pre-algebra just using worksheets.  I'd like to start him on a formal middle school curriculum, preferably one that has rigorous fundamentals, similar to the Spivak calculus book I used way back when.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd recommend looking through some of the 1960s [School Mathematics Study Group (SMSG) books](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/lookupname?key=School%20Mathematics%20Study%20Group)). Even more, I'd recommend getting an older (before 1980 or so) edition of [**Modern algebra. Structure and Method. Book 1**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0007GU5S4) by Mary P Dolciani et al.

Comment: I just noticed your son is 5th grade and apparently is *beginning* middle school math. I saw the title, glanced a few seconds at your last sentence, then went googling for the links to what I thought would be appropriate for someone (apparently not your son, on second reading) who had already been through much of middle school math and was looking for something to self-study at the next level. However, what I gave could still be of use.

Comment: I've seen https://artofproblemsolving.com/ recommended for advanced students in his situation. It is recommended for grades 5+.

Comment: There is no formal middle school curriculum in the U.S. unless you mean Common Core goalposts and textbooks that supposedly align with these goalposts.

Comment: I am not sure about rigour, but you can take a look at the Khan Academy courses ( https://www.khanacademy.org/ ) or the online version of the Big Idea Math books ( https://bim.easyaccessmaterials.com/ ). As far as I can see these are free resources and cover the common core standards in a systematic way.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend starting him with [Beast Academy](https://beastacademy.com/) (maybe even go down to their level 4 or below). Beast Academy is very fun; the rigor may not be obvious, but they are building thinking skills.  When he's done with BA, then go to [Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/).

Comment: Thanks, i looked at BA (which is part of AOPS) and at AOPS and they're great!

Answer (score 3):

You could consider the series distributed in the United States by singaporemath.com:

- *Primary Mathematics* for grades 5 and 6
- *New Elementary Mathematics* for grades 7 and 8.

You can also find later volumes of *New Elementary Mathematics* for grades 9 and 10 for sale on the internet. *Primary Mathematics* has three versions adapted for the U.S., while *New Elementary Mathematics* is not adapted (hence uses metric measures only).

Secondly, for grades 5 to 10, you could consider the recent Australian series *ICE-EM Mathematics*, now in its third edition, whose authors include a number of PhD mathematicians. It is published by the Cambridge University Press and comes recommended by Fields medalist Terence Tao.

Unlike the *Art of Problem Solving* series mentioned in the comments, the Singaporean and Australian series are intended for a wider range of abilities (although *New Elementary Mathematics* is probably for the top 20 to 30% in Singapore schools, which would equate to a smaller percentage in the U.S.)

An alternative to these would be various mid-twentieth century British textbooks aimed at higher achievers, starting from about grade 7 level. One would have to tolerate the fact that they are obviously so old-fashioned, but the level of competence developed in algebra, trigonometry and particularly geometry (in students of a mathematical bent) is without comparison to more recent textbooks.

Comment: Both of these look great

Comment: "the level of competence developed in algebra, trigonometry and particularly geometry is without comparison to more recent textbooks" — this is a nice way of saying that modern math schoolbooks are mostly garbage.